# How to sperate Keras mnist dataset into 5 groups of (0 1), (2 3), (4 5), (6 7), (8 9)

Tags: python, keras, mnist

I am new to machine learning. I am trying to train models on keras mnist dataset. But I want to train the models on the 5 groups sperately. Can someone please advise how to sperate the mnist dataset into the specified groups?

I have tried google for quite some time, but couldn't figure out how to do this.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using a for loop:

```
from keras.datasets import mnist
import numpy as np

(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = mnist.load_data()
images = np.concatenate((train_images, test_images), axis=0)
labels = np.concatenate((train_labels, test_labels), axis=0)
groups = [[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7], [8, 9]]
images_and_labels_by_group = []
for group in groups:
    indices = np.where(np.isin(labels, group))[0]
    group_images = images[indices]
    group_labels = labels[indices]
    images_and_labels_by_group.append((group_images, group_labels))
```

Comment: After what you suggested, I need to split the data in each group into train and test data again. Can I still use something like x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(image_and_labels_by_group[i][0], image_and_labels_by_group[i][1]) for the i group? Will the images and labels still match after train_test_split?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of the ways to achieve that:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

y_train_5cs=np.zeros_like(y_train)
y_test_5cs=np.zeros_like(y_test)

for sn, lbl in enumerate(y_train):
    y_train_5cs[sn]=lbl//2

for sn, lbl in enumerate(y_test):
    y_test_5cs[sn]=lbl//2

print('y_train[:10]:    ', y_train[:10])
print('y_train_5cs[:10]:', y_train_5cs[:10])
print('\n')
print('y_test[:10]:    ', y_test[:10])
print('y_test_5cs[:10]:', y_test_5cs[:10])
```

Output:

```
y_train[:10]:     [5 0 4 1 9 2 1 3 1 4]
y_train_5cs[:10]: [2 0 2 0 4 1 0 1 0 2]

y_test[:10]:     [7 2 1 0 4 1 4 9 5 9]
y_test_5cs[:10]: [3 1 0 0 2 0 2 4 2 4]
```

Comment: Many thanks! Maybe I misunderstood you. But the outputs donot seem like what I asked.